# JQuery bootgrid plugin with ASP.NET Razor pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-bootgrid

I have simple HTML table in Razor view

```
 <table id="grid"  class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
            <tr>
                  <th data-column-id="Detail">
        Detail
      </th>
                <th data-column-id="Client_Ref">
                    Client Ref
                </th>
                <th data-column-id="Acc">
                     Acc
                </th>

            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Detail", new {
   id = item.KeyOfTransaction},
 new { @class = "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-book" })
            </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client_Ref)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Acc)
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

When I apply JQuery Bootgrid, only search field is shown, but whole table become empty

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#grid").bootgrid();
        })

    </script>
}
```

Anyone has idea what is wrong here ? I need to filter data, sort it and do all the other stuff this plugin provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bootgrid` plugin requires that you put your table rows into the `tbody` tags and your header row into the `thead` tag

```
<table id="grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
         <th data-column-id="Detail">
        Detail
      </th>
      <th data-column-id="Client_Ref">
        Client Ref
      </th>
      <th data-column-id="Acc">
        Acc
      </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
<td>
  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Detail", new {
   id = item.KeyOfTransaction},
 new { @class = "btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-book" })
            </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client_Ref)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Acc)
      </td>

    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: great ! that worked before marking your answer as correct i have  1 more question.

Comment: Table has one column with @Html.ActionLink. How do I make this one work ?

Comment: @Jalle what is the problem with the `@Html.ActionLink` is it not rendered or not working correclty?

Comment: @Jalle are you using Bootstrap 4 or Bootstrap 3? Because glyphicon were removed from Boostrap 3 so you need to use a different icon set. Otherwise your actionlink should work fine

Comment: I've fixed it .

Answer (score 0):

`<thead>` and `<tbody>` tag is missing

Example

```
<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
            <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>10238</td>
            <td>eduardo@pingpong.com</td>
            <td>14.10.2013</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```